# Node ORM and Python ORM for same DB?

Tags: python, node.js, postgresql, orm

If I have two backends, one NodeJS and one Python both of them are accessing the same database. Is it possible to use an ORM for both or is that really bad practice? It seems like that would lead to a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

so long as both ORMs put few constraints on the database structure it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it may cause conflicts with table names, constraint names, sequence names and other names which are depend on ORM naming strategy.